# Jenkins and CMake: permission errors

Tags: jenkins, cmake, jenkins-plugins, ros

I installed Jenkins, I'm new to it. Made a user, installed the CMake plugin. I'm trying to compile a simple project just to get started but I cannot even do that.

After complaining of not being able to open some files (like build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log), at the end of the output it says:

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /home/username/development/csa/build/CMakeCache.txt.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. /home/username/development/csa/build/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
Build step 'CMake Build' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

To me this is clearly a permissions issue. The build directory is empty, it has not done anything. I created a user, started jenkins and either of the following had no effect on the output:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start --user jenkins
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start --user username
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start
```

I'm not even trying to compile the code, just trying to build the cmake files... my configuration is like this: (as simple as possible)

[image]

I did add a working directory which is in my home folder so I do have permissions for it.

EDIT: I changed the ownership of the build folder to jenkins, created a user group called jenkinsusers, added myself and jenkins to the group, and gave the group read/write permissions. It appears to work now. But I'm not sure this is the standard way to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not sure this is the right way but this is how I did it: I changed the owner of the directory to jenkins.

The workspace folder is under my home directory (~/myproject/build). That's probably the issue. The compiling gets done using catkin_make, a tool from ROS.